# IF statement gives wrong outcome when 1 string is being searched multiple times

Tags: php, string, stripos

So i have these two strings:

```
$title = 'Chair Material Suede Black';

$title = 'Chair Material Suede Red';
```

This is a snippet from my PHP function:

```
elseif (stripos($title, 'Suede') !== false) {
    if (stripos($title, 'Red') !== false) {
        return 'Red Suede Chair';
    }
    else {return "TEMP_Category";}
}
```

The function continues, and 50 lines down there is this code:

```
elseif (stripos($title, 'Suede') !== false) {
        if (stripos($title, 'Black') !== false) {
            return 'Black Suede Chair';
        }
        else {return "TEMP_Category";}
    }
```

However, the string `'Chair Material Suede Black'` ALWAYS returns `'TEMP_Category'`, because the search for `'Red'` and `'Suede'` is done prior to the Black one.

Is there any way to let it pass to the `'black'` search?

Comment: Probably because it's hitting the suede/red block, first. Add the Black check inside of the first Suede check, with an `else if`.

Comment: `if (hasSuede) { if(isRed){return "red";} elseif(isBlue) {return "blue";} return "Suede"; }`

Comment: You have two strings in the same variable?

Answer (score 3):

Combine the two checks:

```
elseif (stripos($title, 'Suede') !== false && stripos($title, 'Red') !== false) {
```

And move the else with TEMP_Category to the end of the checks.

```
elseif (stripos($title, 'Suede') !== false && stripos($title, 'Red') !== false) {
    return 'Red Suede Chair';
} elseif (stripos($title, 'Suede') !== false && stripos($title, 'Black') !== false) {
    return 'Black Suede Chair';
} else {
    return "TEMP_Category";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, the string 'Chair Material Suede Black' ALWAYS returns
>   'TEMP_Category', because the search for 'Red' and 'Suede' is done
>   prior to the Black one.

Just for clarity that's simply because you're using `elseif (stripos($title, 'Suede') !== false)`. So you will never reach the second (btw. *identical*) condition. PHP will skip every other `elseif` after a first matching condition. 
And because the first one will return "TEMP_Category" (because it's not *Red*) you get the wrong result.

Accept the answer from @Fenton because it's how you can solve it ;-)